# cgo: pointer to go strings's contents

Tags: string, go, boxing, cgo

I need to pass Go string to C code, but I don't want to copy the string by using the `func C.CString(string) *C.char` My C code doesn't change the string, so I wanted to avoid useless copying for my read-only code and save some CPU cycles.

P.S.:
It seems my idea is dangerous: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/golang-nuts/iWGS09kWKbQ/Wx8cB7WyOSQJ

Comment: You can't directly take the address of the string data. Why not just keep the data in a `[]byte` which is addressable?

Comment: @JimB can I pass an address of `bytearray[0]` to C code? What if Go decided to garbage-collect the `[]bytearray` while my C code is still executing?

Comment: It's up to you to keep the value alive while the call is executing, and the same thing would apply even if it was a string. The C code isn't allowed to keep a copy of the pointer after the call returns, so keeping the value in scope is usually trivial.

Comment: @JimB as I understand, it is enough to keep a reference to `[]byte` in scope of calling my C code to prevent it to be GC'd?

Comment: yes, that is correct, and again, the same would apply for a string. `[]byte` isn't collected and differently from `string`

Comment: @JimB Ok, but string -> []byte conversion implies the copying I wanted to avoid. So I should change my interfaces for working with []byte as more general-purpose.

Comment: yes, if you want to avoid copying. If the strings are relatively small, the cgo call is going to dominate the time far more than copying.

Comment: @JimB do you mean go -> C call is heavier than C -> C_library code? Why?

Comment: Go isn't C, and they have different calling conventions. Saving the Go stack and switching to the C stack takes more time than calling a function directly.